# Backbone click on disabled button event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I use backbone and here is my view:

```
view = Backbone.View.extend({
events: {

 'click #but': 'someAction'

},

someAction: function(){
   alert('yo!');
}

});
```

This code doesn't work if #but is disabled. Which event I have to use for disabled buttons?

Comment: If events on disabled elements is your concern this might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391170/jquery-register-click-event-while-button-is-disabled

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109228/clicking-a-disabled-input-or-button

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your html make something like this, wrap your button in div:

```
<div id='butWrapper'>
    <button id="but" disabled></button>
</div>
```

And in view code hadle event on this wrapper:

```
events: {
 'click #butWrapper': 'someAction'
},
```